# Electrical service Load Calulations

Tags: electrical

When preforming Load calculations to consolidate service panels, on Step 1. do you add the VA for square footage on the sub panel and the main panel as separate calculations for each panel?

Comment: You might check the service load section from the IRC instead: [IRC E3602.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-36-services#IRC2021P1_Pt08_Ch36_SecE3602.2). Depending on how your locality has done its code amendments, the stricter of the IRC and the NEC could be your code. Regardless, I doubt that they differ for something like service load. The IRC should be more user friendly in its presentation, though.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a calculation of the **required size of the service** to feed the house.

**That** does not change if the house has one panel feeding everything or 17 sub-panels feeding the loads. That's distribution, not service size.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I don't understand.  I'm rearranging circuits from main panel and 2 sub panels to result in a main panel, 1 sub panel.  I have preformed the load calculations for the service to include all loads  for the main service panel (IAW 220 NEC). Why would I need to double up the load calculations for the house area (x3VA/SQ. FT.) for the sub panel? Isn't that doubling up the loads for the distribution?

Comment: You double up square footage because it's in the load calculation. It seems a bit silly but that's how it goes. You could figure out about how much square footage is dedicated to each panel, then use that number for your calculation. It might be easier to put all the dedicated loads in the main panel, then all the convenience lighting loads in the sub panel. That way you're only counting the square footage once, and you probably get to have smaller feeders. Or if the panels are close together, use huge feeders and you don't have to think about it as much.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a load calculation per panel.  And a panel's calculation needs to include the contents of any subpanels it powers.

For instance if you're using NEC 220.82, and you are dealing with loads that fall under "the first 10k VA plus 40% of the remaining VA", if you have 3 subpanels of 15k VA each, for each sub that folds down to 12 kVA. But for the main panel feeds only those 3 subpanels, then it calculates 45 kVA through that same formula, giving 24 kVA not 36 kVA as you might expect.

Or you calculate HVAC as 100% of the larger of heating or A/C load… suppose one subpanel has 6kVA of heating load and another subpanel has 5kVA of air conditioning load.   The A/C load subpanel counts as full boat 5kVA, since it sees 0 VA of heating load and 5k VA of A/C load.  But for the main panel feeding both of them, it doesn't count as 11k VA: since it sees a 6k VA heating or 5k VA air conditioning load, it takes the larger and that's it.

Comment: The purpose of the 10kVA + 40% is a probabilistic thing, where the code's assuming that every demand source is not getting stressed to capacity at the same time, right?

Comment: @popham yes, it's for demand factors / load diversity, and data has proven it works well in dwellings.  Of course all this data was developed pre-EV, but EV is generally counted as full 100-125% depending on the AHJ.  In non-dwellings you're forced into the big-boy formula in the rest of Article 220.